# Replace onclick specific parameter by click on div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building Custom Cart, where i show product detail on same page in Popup model with jQuery onclick, But on Popup window i also want to update **product_ID** on "Add to Cart" Button in onclick's first Parameter, Here is the code for demonsration:

**Product Thumbnail:**

```
<div id="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
    <input type="hidden" value="159" />
</div>
```

**Popup Add to Cart Button**

```
<a href="#" onclick="add_to_cart('Product_ID', 'Product_Price');">Add to Cart</a>
```

what i want is when i click on product `<div id="product">` than the value in the hidden input is also updated on Add to Cart button with first parameter of **onclick attr** which is **Product_ID**, any help regarding this would be highly appreciable.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this issue on following fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/SJP7k/14/

Comment: Just to note, your example above does not contain one scrap of Jquery. It's all pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/SJP7k/17/)

**Jquery**

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
var ProductID = $('div').find('#ProductID').attr('value');
    var Price = $('div').find('#price').attr('value');

$('div').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('a').attr('onclick', function (i, v) {
        v=v.replace('Product ID',ProductID);
        return v.replace('Product Price',Price);
    });
});

    });

function add_to_cart(productid,price)
{
    alert(productid+"/"+price);
}
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: another question, what if the value of parameter is dynamic, i mean we've replaced the value of **"Product Price"** by matching the value string, so instead of **"Product Price"** there would some random value!

So how can we only update specific (1st or 2nd) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To 'quick fix' this code, you could user something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJP7k/15/

Fiddle HTML

```
<div id="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
    <input type="hidden" value="159" />
</div>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" id="add" data-product="10" data-price="9.95">Add to Cart btn in popup</a>
```

Fiddle JS

```
$('#product').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ProductID = $(this).find('input').attr('value');
    $('#add').data('product', ProductID);
});

$('#add').click(function () {
    alert('PRODUCT: ' + $(this).data('product') + ' PRICE: $' + $(this).data('price'));
});
```